# Coloring facets of histograms in ggplot by grouping variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I thought this would be an easy one, but not quite so.

I have my code for some histograms in facets. They can follow the standard color theme no problem, but if I want to have them follow a palette (which works fine for e.g. a single scatterplot with dots from different groups) everything goes haywire.

And where the heck does the red come in?

Data here: https://pastebin.com/0p7SP005

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(data = point_list, aes(x = lifetime,
                              y = ..density..)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    aes(fill = as.factor(cluster),
        col = "black") + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2.6,50),
                    ylim = c(0,0.16)) +
    theme_tufte(base_size = 11, base_family = "Helvetica") +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.7),
          legend.position = "none") +
    facet_wrap(~cluster, scales = "free", ) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

For reference, Set1 should look like this:
[image]

Comment: in `aes` it is not col, but `color`

Comment: Your `fill` and `facet_wrap` variables should be the same. `cluster` and `as.factor(cluster)` might well be different.  Also, in your final line you probably want `scale_fill_brewer`.

Comment: oh, it's the `scale_fill_brewer` that escaped me! Suddenly everything makes sense. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll illustrate the point about why the bars' outlines were red, since everything else has been covered already.

In your code, you had `col = "black"` inside the aesthetic mapping function, which meant that color (used for outlines) is mapped to a variable. "black" in this case would be interpreted as a factor with 1 level. Since your code also includes `scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")`, the resulting color is the first color from the Set1 palette, i.e. bright red.

(The actual word didn't matter; if you had `col = "white"` or anything like that, it would make no difference at all.)

If you had chosen a different palette, the outline color would be different too. For example:

```
ggplot(data = point_list, aes(x = lifetime,
                              y = ..density..)) +
  geom_histogram(size = 3) + # thicker outline to make the color more obvious
  aes(fill = as.factor(cluster),
      col = "black") + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2.6,50),
                  ylim = c(0,0.16)) +
  # theme_tufte(base_size = 11, base_family = "Helvetica") + #commenting this out since I don't have this theme
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.7),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~cluster, scales = "free", ) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

[image: example]

The first color from the Set2 palette is pale-ish green (#66c2a5), which is what we see here.

To get black outlines, follow loki's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45729891/8449629) above to specify the color in `geom_histogram`, and make sure you do it outside `aes()` this time. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the red to black just change your `geom_histogram` line to:

```
geom_histogram(color = "black")
```

[image]